# Exit code of redirected command

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

So I want to verify the exit code of a specific command

```
runuser -s /bin/bash @user_name -c $command > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

How can I find whether the command `runuser -s /bin/bash @user_name -c $command` executed correctly?
I tried using `$?` but it doesn't work because it is always 0 ( the result of redirection is 0)

How can i find the exit code of that command  ?

Comment: your program is running in background.

Comment: Do not deface your posts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The exit code is not available due to the backgrounding of the task (via `&`), *not* the redirection.

You should use [wait](http://www.unixcl.com/2008/06/bash-wait-command.html) to get the exit code of a background task.

> wait command stop script execution until all jobs running in
>   background have terminated, or until the job number or process id
>   specified as an option terminates. It returns the exit status of
>   waited-for command.

Comment: What if the program would not be running in background, Brian? Could I get exit code too?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$!` in bash to get the pid of last background process. Then you can do `wait pid`. This waits until the process with pid is complete.

So for your script you can do something like this:

```
runuser -s /bin/bash @user_name -c $command > /dev/null 2>&1 &
myPid=$!
wait $myPid
status=$?
echo "Exit status of the process with pid: $myPid is $status"
```